# optimising algorithms in R for regression parameters

Tags: r, cross-validation, predictive-models, optimization

I am seeking more guidance than actual answer and if someone can point me to the right direction, it would be great. Suppose I have an equation of loss which is

```
loss = (guaranteed production - production)
```

I collected `loss` and `guaranteed` production data for 1990 - 2010. I have a model that predicts `production` using the following equation:

```
Model_production = intercept + a*x1 - b*x2 + c*x3 + d*x4 - e*x5
```

In order to train the above model, I compiled `production` data from 1970-2010 years and there is quite a good correlation between 'Model_production' and `production` for these years. I then used the model to calculate Model_loss for 1990-2010

```
  Model_loss = (guaranteed production - Model_production)
```

I compare how close my `Model_loss` and `loss` are using `rmse` or pearsons correlation. Suppose if I model is a bad fit or I am aiming to obtain a pearson correlation close to 0.8 and but I actually around 0.6. Is there any method of optimising the parameters `(a, b, c, d, e)` furthermore of my model such that I get a reasonable fit between the `Model_loss` and `loss` without having to recalibrate the `Model_production` model.

In essence, are there any methods that takes in a set of parameters and iterates over it to give me the best fit between loss and model loss.

Comment: This might not be what you’re looking for, but have you tried nonlinear combinations like $ab$ and $d^2$? Also, is your poor performance on training data or when you test on data that the model has not seen?

Comment: I have modified the question giving some more explanation. I have tried non-linear combinations but removed it from the above example to make the question brief. In nut shell, the issue isn't with the production model but rather with the loss since the loss data comes from different source.